# Explicit template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to compile with explicit template instatiation only.

Consider this dummy snippet

```
#include <vector>

template struct std::allocator<int>;
template struct std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>;

void fun(){
  std::vector<int> v;
}

int main (){
  fun();
};
```

I would like to compile it with

```
g++ -std=c++11  -fno-implicit-templates fun.cc
```

I expected this to work, however it complains of unresolved references to `std::vector` member functions. Shouldn't member functions be automatically instantiated along with the `std::vector` class? How can I make it work?

The compiler error is:

```
/tmp/cc1QxQUn.o: In function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&)':
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE9push_backERKi[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE9push_backERKi]+0x65): undefined reference to `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<int const&>(int const&)'
/tmp/cc1QxQUn.o: In function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int&&)':
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE9push_backEOi[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE9push_backEOi]+0x2a): undefined reference to `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::emplace_back<int>(int&&)'
/tmp/cc1QxQUn.o: In function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)':
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE6insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiS1_EERS4_[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE6insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiS1_EERS4_]+0x14d): undefined reference to `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux<int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&&)'
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE6insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiS1_EERS4_[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE6insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiS1_EERS4_]+0x166): undefined reference to `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux<int const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)'
/tmp/cc1QxQUn.o: In function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&&)':
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE6insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiS1_EEOi[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE6insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiS1_EEOi]+0x32): undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::emplace<int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&&)'
/tmp/cc1QxQUn.o: In function `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_assign_dispatch<int const*>(int const*, int const*, std::__false_type)':
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE18_M_assign_dispatchIPKiEEvT_S5_St12__false_type[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE18_M_assign_dispatchIPKiEEvT_S5_St12__false_type]+0x2d): undefined reference to `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_assign_aux<int const*>(int const*, int const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)'
/tmp/cc1QxQUn.o: In function `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_dispatch<int const*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const*, int const*, std::__false_type)':
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE18_M_insert_dispatchIPKiEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EET_S9_St12__false_type[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE18_M_insert_dispatchIPKiEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EET_S9_St12__false_type]+0x32): undefined reference to `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_range_insert<int const*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const*, int const*, std::forward_iterator_tag)'
/tmp/cc1QxQUn.o: In function `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_assign_dispatch<std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >(std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::__false_type)':
vec.cc:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE18_M_assign_dispatchISt13move_iteratorIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EEEEEvT_S9_St12__false_type[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE18_M_assign_dispatchISt13move_iteratorIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EEEEEvT_S9_St12__false_type]+0x2d): undefined reference to `void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_assign_aux<std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >(std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::forward_iterator_tag)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [temp.explicit]:

> An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the
>   same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members (**not including** members inherited from base
>   classes and **members that are templates**) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation
>   unit containing the explicit instantiation, except as described below.

So while you're explicitly instantiating `std::vector<int>`, you're not instantiating any of its member function templates - so you're getting undefined references for all of those (e.g. `_M_emplace_back_aux` is a function template). You'd have to add all of those explicitly:

```
template void std::vector<int>::_M_emplace_back_aux<int>(int&& );
template void std::vector<int>::_M_emplace_back_aux<const int&>(const int& );
template void std::vector<int>::_M_assign_aux<int const*>(int const*, int const*, std::forward_iterator_tag);
...
```

Or just - let implicit instantiation just do its thing.